# PySpark: Change column's value inside a dataframe based on previous values

Tags: sql, pyspark, window

I want to create dates intervals (date +/-10 days) using pyspark and change them based on the date and the previous intervals. If the new date is outside the calculated interval for a given id, an new interval will be computed, otherwise, the interval is set. For example:
Initial dataframe:

```
       |id|date|
       |a|2019-02-14|
       |a|2019-02-14|
       |a|2019-01-11|
       |a|2019-01-14|
       |a|2019-01-16|
       |a|2019-01-22|
       |b|2019-01-25|
       |b|2019-02-10|
       |b|2019-02-04|
       |b|2019-02-10|
       |b|2019-02-02|
```

What I want:

```
       |id|date      |LB        |UB        |
       |a |2019-02-14|2019-02-04|2019-02-24|
       |a |2019-02-14|2019-02-04|2019-02-24|
       |a |2019-01-11|2019-01-01|2019-01-21|
       |a |2019-01-14|2019-01-01|2019-01-21|
       |a |2019-01-16|2019-01-01|2019-01-21|
       |a |2019-01-22|2019-01-12|2019-02-01|
       |b |2019-01-25|2019-01-15|2019-02-04|
       |b |2019-02-04|2019-01-15|2019-02-04|
       |b |2019-02-10|2019-02-01|2019-02-20|
       |b |2019-02-02|2019-02-01|2019-02-20|
```

I create the columns LB & UB using `df = df.withColumn("LB", expr("date_add(date,-10)"))`. But I get the intervals for each row. I try to create window but I cannot change the value based on previous row.
How Could create these columns?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

What is it that you want to do with the windows? Because, since Spark 2.0 you should be able to use a window function:
But you need to aggregate as well.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import window

df.groupBy(window("date", windowDuration="30 days")).count()
```

You should get a result like :

```
+---------------------------------------------+-----+
|window                                       |count|
+---------------------------------------------+-----+
|[2016-01-30 01:00:00.0,2016-02-29 01:00:00.0]|1    |
|[2015-12-31 01:00:00.0,2016-01-30 01:00:00.0]|2    |
|[2016-03-30 02:00:00.0,2016-04-29 02:00:00.0]|1    |
+---------------------------------------------+-----+
```

It's sort of a hack to create `10 days` window and then join it back onto the original dataframe. If you want, you can add a `monotonically_increasing_id` to keep every row unique and then use `df.groupBy(window("date", windowDuration="30 days"), "id").count()`, after which you can drop the `count` column.

It can get tricky when the dates are time-zone aware.

Let me know about the use-case so I can tune my answer accordingly.

Comment: I ordered rows according to `id` and `updated_date`, and I want to create dates intervals based on previous rows by maintaining the same order.

Comment: You don't need to order by ID. Just use it how I have demonstrated. You can use `lag` or `lead` functions.

Comment: The goal of my work, is to recompute the interval once the date is out of it, and to re-verify it for all next dates, for that, I need that all dates will be ordered by `updated_date`, then I want to use something like: `when((col('date') < col('LB_date'))|(col('date') >col('UB_date'))` change the interval, `otherwise` keep it. After, I want to see how many times, we recompute this interval.

Comment: Oh so you don't want a window of +/-10 days window from the `date` column (Spark operates row-wise)? 
My suggestion is to use `lag` and `lead` functions to create the conditions, and recompute the interval using any of the dates in any of the date columns.

Comment: Could you please give me an example?

Comment: Using lag we get the value from previous row, but I want to dynamically change the intervals like in a loop.